# Copying data to an integer pointer array through loop?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, heap-memory

I am facing issue copying data to void pointer array through for loop. I am not allowed to use double pointer.

I am trying someting like this:

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
   array + i = i;
}
```

but I cant just do this, and I know that,

I am trying to do it like this

```
memcpy(
  array+i,
  i,
  s
);
```

I have already allocated memory:
My actual code is some thing like this:

```
if(v->e_type==V_INT){
  //  printf("%p ",v->e_array+v->no_e);
        memcpy(
               v->e_array+v->no_e,
               new_val,
               v->e_sz
               );
}
```

Comment: using double pointer its very simple like this:
v->e_array[v->no_e]=new_val;

Comment: Unless you show us how each variable is declared, allocated and passed as a parameter, all anyone can do is guess. Your `v->e_array[v->no_e]=new_val;` may very well need to be `(v->e_array)[v->no_e]=new_val;`, but there is no way to tell with what you posted.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `->` and `[]` have the same precedence, and left-to-right associativity, so the parentheses are not needed, right?

Comment: yeah but the thing is I am not allowed to used double pointer

Comment: But what are you using? We don't know because you didn't show us.  You just said pointer array, which is not clear at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
```

You can put values in it with pointer arithmetic:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    *(x+i) = i; // or *(x+1) = 0; for example
}
```

Or simply:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    x[i] = i;
}
```